# Why couldn't the dwarves beat/kill the Balrog?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, dwarves, balrogs

We read that the dwarves fled Moria after the Balrog killed Durin, their king.

My question is: was it beyond the power of the dwarves to kill the Balrog? If so, how come elves were able to kill them? What was it in the elves that made it possible for them to kill a Balrog, while the dwarves were unable to do so?

Comment: We don't really know the circumstances - what dwarves tried, how balrog reacted, etc. If this was real world then they should have defeated him, but we're talking Tolkien here - it needed Gandalf's sacrifice, not a a tactically used cave-in, to kill the balrog.

Comment: Aren't we talking about Feanor-level Elves when discussing killing a Balrog? I mean, those were primal High Elves, nearly demigods at the hight of their power. Dwarves are strong and sturdy, and can really swing an axe, but I feel like these guys are in entirely different leagues, no?

Comment: "was it beyond the power of the dwarves to kill the Balrog?"  **Obviously**.  Otherwise, they would have killed it...

Comment: @MishaR That's basically the answer! Though I don't think you needed Feanor to kill a balrog. Didn't Glorfindel kill one, in his previous life?

Comment: Feanor and co were like Level 20, with 10-15 more epic levels. They had really high attack and damage bonuses, insane HP, etc. The Moria dwarves were like level 15 *at best*, a lot of them are just level 1 NPC classes. The Balrogs are like level 20-equivalent by default, and then the Moria balrog is a special one that has extra levels on top of that.

Comment: @Blueriver Well, chronologically speaking, it's more like the answer is basically my comment :) I don't think Feanor himself killed any Balrogs, although I would definitely rank him as a Feanor-level Elf.

Answer (score 105):

There was nothing particular about the elves that made them capable of taking on balrogs, except that the elves, as the Firstborn [children of Illúvatar](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Children_of_Il%C3%BAvatar), were probably the most powerful of all the races native to Arda (meaning, not counting [Ainur](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Ainur) like Gandalf).  What was more important was that the greatest warriors—the kind who might have faced down a balrog—were, by and large, no longer to be found in Middle-earth.

Gandalf is explicit that no one else in the Company, including the elf lord [Legolas](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Legolas), is a match for the balrog.

> ‘Fly!  This is a foe beyond any of you.  I must hold the narrow way.  Fly!’

Indeed, Legolas, who normally seems to have ice water in his veins, is quite un-manned (or un-elfed) by the sudden appearance of [Durin's Bane](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Durin%27s_Bane).

> Legolas turned and set an arrow to the string, though it was a long shot for his small bow.  He drew, but his hand fell, and the arrow slipped to the ground.  He gave a cry of dismay and fear.  Two great trolls appeared; they bore great slabs of stone, and flung them down to serve as gangways over the fire.  But it was not the trolls that had filled the Elf with terror.  The ranks of the ores had opened, and they crowded away, as if they themselves were afraid. Something was coming up behind them.  What it was could not be seen:  it was like a great shadow, in the middle of which was a dark form, of man-shape maybe, yet greater; and a power and terror seemed to be in it and to go before it.
>
> ...
>
> ‘Ai!  ai!’  wailed  Legolas.  ‘A  Balrog!  A  Balrog  is  come!’

Tolkien's Middle-earth is fundamentally a fallen world, in which the greatness of the past is always ebbing away, because of the way the world had been corrupted by Morgoth.  Everything is less than it once was, and this manifests itself in many ways.  For example, the greatest creations of the elves and Ainur, about which most of Tolkien's stories ultimately revolve—whether the [Two Trees](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Two_Trees_of_Valinor), the [Silmarils](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Silmarils) that contained their light, or the [Rings of Power](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Rings_of_Power)—are artifacts that can only be made once; the power to duplicate them no longer exists.*

Similarly, there were many more heroes who *might* have challenged a balrog during the Elder Days.  [Ecthelion](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Ecthelion) and [Glorfindel](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Glorfindel) each killed a balrog during the Fall of Gondolin, although they lost their own lives in the process.**  Yet they were just two among the [twelve greatest nobles of the city](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Twelve_houses_of_the_Gondothlim), any of whom could have stood a chance against a balrog.  However, even the likes of Ecthelion and Glorfindel probably needed to get lucky; even the high king of the Noldor, [Fingon the Valiant](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Fingon), had lost out to the lord of balrogs when they faced off during the [Nirnaeth Arnoediad](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Nirnaeth_Arnoediad).  [Húrin](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/H%C3%BArin), the  strongest of all human warriors, killed seventy trolls at the Battle of Unnumbered Tears, and he was only captured because he fought so fast and hard that the blade of his battle-axe melted.  The greatest warriors among the Men of the Third Age, Húrin's kinsmen [Isildur](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Isildur) and [Aragorn](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Aragorn), could never have done that.***

Simply put, although the Company contained some of the most illustrious heroes of the Third Age, by that time there was probably no one native to Middle-earth with the might to face down a balrog.  Gandalf (at least after his return) is the second-most-powerful being in Middle-earth, and even for him, the struggle against the balrog is still too much for him to survive.  Moreover, even though Gandalf gives Durin's Bane a warning—cryptically identifying himself as a Maia and revealing that he recognizes the balrog's Ainur nature as well—

> ‘I am a servant of the Secret Fire, wielder of the flame of Anor.  You cannot pass. The dark fire will not avail you, flame of Udûn.  Go back to the Shadow!  You cannot pass.’

Durin's Bane is not fazed and knows that he stands a reasonable chance against Gandalf.

*Or, at least, the power needed to make such things again cannot be harnessed while Morgoth's corruption remains sullying the world.  According to the [Second Prophecy of Mandos](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Dagor_Dagorath), only when Morgoth is slain in the Battle of Battles and the Great Enemy's taint is expunged in other ways (most notably, via [Fëanor](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/F%C3%ABanor)'s repentance of his own crimes) can the Two Trees be regrown as part of the [Second Music](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Second_Music_of_the_Ainur), as part of the complete remaking of the world.

**Presumably, other balrogs were slain during the greatest conflicts of the First Age—the [War for Sake of the Elves](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Battle_of_the_Powers) and the [War of Wrath](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/War_of_Wrath)—but the tactical details of those conflicts were never recorded in Tolkien's works.

***The first-time reader of *The Fellowship of the Ring* probably will not appreciate the magnitude of the compliment that Elrond offers to Frodo at the end of "The Council of Elrond," but (although Frodo is not primarily a warrior, but rather a martyr archetype) Elrond's estimation of him very high, ranking Frodo among heroes whose like no longer seems to exist.

> ‘But it is a heavy burden.  So heavy that none could lay it on another.  I do not lay it on you.  But if you take it freely, I will say that your choice is right; and though all the mighty Elf-friends of old, Hador, and Húrin, and Túrin, and Beren himself were assembled together, your seat should be among them.’

Comment: +1 for recognizing that the fundamental reason is that *Arda is a fallen world* and the glory of the past is irrecoverably lost.

Comment: And hence why the Age of Men was certain to come: Men are simply more able to deal with Arda as it is, instead of as how they might wish it to be. (Not that all Men did so, or even very many of them.) Meanwhile the Firstborn and the Ainur spend the remainder of Arda's days in their nostalgia festival.

Comment: Elrond basically says he's not trying to force Frodo to take the ring, but then in the same breath - whether intentional or not - it sounds like he manipulates Frodo by mentioning the glory he could have if he agrees to continue.

Comment: *"The ranks of the or**e**s had opened"* - I think you've got the same badly OCRed edition I once read

Comment: @ChrisH I was copying from an edition on the Internet Archive.  Although I was referring to my paper copy, it was easier to copy the text from online than to type in each passage by hand (and probably introduce new errors of my own!).

Comment: Be that as it may, it seems that a balrog can be subdued or at least buried by a great mass of stone. Its physical strength is not extreme, and it can also fall into an abyss. I've not heard of balrogs' being able to dis through massive heaps of stone. So I wonder why the dwarves didn't set a trap, have some enormous cavern collapse onto the balrog.

Comment: I would add to it, this Balrog is expected to be among the most powerful since it managed to endure when the others were swept away.

Comment: @Buzz the same one then - I was glad of it even so, as it gave me something to read while stuck in hospital far from home

Comment: The Rings of Power are quite a new creation. I'm pretty sure they could have been replicated. They just didn't out of fear of the One. Saruman makes some sort of ring for example. It's just the One that requires a powerful Ainu to bind themselves into it, and Sauron was the greatest that was left in Middle-Earth. By the Fourth Age, and no more Elf Lords, then it would be impossible, and there's no need for them in Aman.

Comment: @cerberus, at some point, albeit the immense depth of Tolkiens works, the story just has to go on. You know... "The movie is called `On The Run`, not `Caught Within 5 Minutes`." ;)

Comment: @AnoE: Hmm not sure I follow, but I'm certainly not complaining that we get to see a Balrog in LotR!

Comment: @Cerberus You don't really know what tricks the Balrog can pull. For example, it might look like the Balrog and Galdalf were essentially not doing anything that two brawling dwarves would be incapable of, but that could just they were both equals and had to resort to nothing brute force. Kind of like in Dune where they just fight like people in medieval times. But that's just because the fancy tricks on both sides cancel each other out. Who knows what fancier tricks the Balrog has against lesser beings?

Comment: @DKNguyen: Good theory, it could be something like that.

Comment: @OrangeDog Celebrimbor wasn't around anymore though.

Comment: @Buzz couldn't Glorfindel stand a chance against a Balrog during the third age? Not that he would have helped Durin's people (not even sure he was in Middle Earth at that point), but I'm curious. Same question for Saruman at the height of his power, Elrond (though he wasn't a great warrior, right?), Galadriel, and Gil-Galad before he died.

Comment: *Gandalf (at least after his return) is the second-most-powerful being in Middle-earth* -Truly? I'd have thought there are at least two beings more powerful than Gandalf (Saruman & Sauron).

Comment: @Allure Gandalf is explicit about this in "The White Rider":  "‘Dangerous!’ cried Gandalf.  ‘And so am I, very dangerous: more dangerous than anything you will ever meet, unless you are brought alive before the seat of the Dark Lord....'"  He also explains his status vis-a-vis Saruman:  "‘Yes, I am white now,’ said Gandalf.  ‘Indeed I am Saruman, one might almost say, Saruman as he should have been.  But come now, tell me of yourselves!  I have passed through fire and deep water, since we parted.  I have forgotten much that I thought I knew, and learned again much that I had forgotten....'"

Comment: @Buzz hmm, I interpreted those sentences to mean that Gandalf is not as *dangerous* as Sauron, but not to mean that he is the second-most powerful being in Middle-earth. In particular, he doesn't claim to be more powerful than Cirdan, Elrond, Galadriel, Tom Bombadil, etc., only that those other powerful beings are on their side, so they are not dangerous. As for Saruman, Gandalf seems to say they are equally powerful, only.

Comment: @Allure On the contrary, Gandalf seems to be saying that although he is the most dangerous individual apart from Sauron, Gimli does not really need to worry, since he and Gandalf is securely on the same side.  For much the same reason, the dwarf does not need to worry about Fangorn, about which Gimli had been quite concerned.  As to Gandalf relative to Saruman, when they faced off a few chapters later, it was hardly a contest—Saruman having given up his color and "left the path of wisdom."

Answer (score 18):

The short and simple answer is that Noldor in the First Age who had returned to Middle-Earth from Valinor and fought the Long War against Morgoth and his armies were bigger badasses than simple residents of a dwarven kingdom in the Third Age several thousand years later. There are two elves credited with killing Balrogs, Ecthelion and Glorfindel, both during the fall of Gondolin, both dying in the process, and the city still fell regardless.

Answer (score 14):

A balrog is essentially a minor deity, and effectively immortal.
Only the great magics of the first and second age could destroy one, hence neither of the mortal races would stand a chance against one.

Gandalf, being similarly a minor deity, nearly perished fighting one, and even then we do NOT know whether this killed the balrog or merely caused it to retreat!

So the dwarves never stood a chance. At most they could hope to slow the creature down by blocking its path to their halls, but they would not have been able to stop it. Neither did the fellowship, obviously, which is why Gandalf sacrificed himself to give them time to escape, nearly perishing in the process.

Comment: Great answer!  You write Gandalf the Grey "nearly perished". He actually did perish, and was sent back after, as Gandalf the White.

Comment: If Gandalf is to be believed (and there's no particular reason *not* to), he did kill the Balrog.

Comment: @Andomar, That depends on what you mean by, "perish." Somewhere in Tolkien's writings, ISTR he describes how beings like Gandalf wear their physical bodies in the same way that we wear clothes. The physical body that he wore as "Gandalf the Grey" was destroyed, but the being who was sent back as "Gandalf the White" to finish what he had started was essentially the same person even if there were a few of his old memories that he could only dimly recall.

Comment: @SolomonSlow In the same sense as OP meant "elves [...] could kill a Balrog" Gandalf was also killed. Given that balrogs are also maiar, they can also not be killed in the same sense as mortals can. Though I don't recall any of them recovering physical form it is not outside of the realm of possibility.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Though of course Gandalf the White looks exactly like Gandalf the Grey, (not just in the films, even in the books all the characters who knew him still recognize him as Gandalf), so if it's a new body, it sure doesn't look new.  Of course every iteration of Gandalf (and Saruman and the other wizards) are always shown as old men in appearance, so we have no idea what a "new" version would look like...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman that's why I don't think Gandalf actually died and was resurrected. The book clearly shows him making his way to the top of the mountain where the eagles found him. I have always assumed him surviving but seriously injured.

Comment: "Then darkness took me, and I strayed out of thought and time, and I wandered far on roads that I will not tell. Naked I was **sent back** [to the mountain top]". Gandalf's *mortal* body (the *real* one, not the facsimile any Ainu can assume) was killed, and his spirt presumably did not simply return to Aman, but was reembodied by Eru.